# Web API post returns bad request in Fiddler but Ok in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am attempting to write a web API where our clients can post submission data to us for future validation. I have this (much simplified) class which is what the user posts to us:

```
public class ClientSubmission
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 40)]
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }

    [StringLength(maximumLength: 250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my API controller:

```
public class RebateController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost] // This is probably unnecessary but it's in the code so I put it here
    public IHttpActionResult New(ClientSubmission content)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok(content);
        }

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

In Fiddler when I pass a JSON object with `ApiKey` I get the object back, and when I don't I get the ModelState errors back - exactly what I expect! However, in my two unit tests I get back `OkNegotiatedContentResult<ClientSubmission>` for both tests. What am I doing wrong?

```
[TestClass]
public class RebateControllerTest
{
    private readonly RebateController _controller;

    public RebateControllerTest()
    {
        _controller = new RebateController();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidApiReturnsOk()
    {
        var payload = GetDefault();

        var actionResult = _controller.New(payload);

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof (OkNegotiatedContentResult<ClientSubmission>));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void NullApiReturnsBadRequest()
    {
        var payload = GetDefault();

        payload.ApiKey = null;

        var actionResult = _controller.New(payload);

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof (BadRequestResult));
    }

    private static ClientSubmission GetDefault()
    {
        return new ClientSubmission
        {
            ApiKey = "test api key",
            Name = "first name"
        };
    }
}
```

Failing test:

[image: Failing test]

Comment: Not passing any JSON is not the same as passing data with one property equal to null

Comment: A null ApiKey results in an invalid ModelState, which would trigger the BadRequest() (or at least it does in Fiddler).